# DAO methods all return NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, apache-tomee

I'm developing a little web app for an exam purpose, but I'm encountering several problems with the Dao methods, they all return a NullPointerException.

This is the Façade:

```
@Stateless(name = "administratorFacade")
    public class AdministratorFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "clinic-unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Administrator getAdministrator(String username){
        AdministratorDaoJPA administratorDao = new AdministratorDaoJPA();
        Administrator administrator = administratorDao.findByUsername(username);
        return administrator;
    } //An example of method that uses DAO
```

This is the DAO:

```
public class AdministratorDaoJPA implements AdministratorDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "clinic-unit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
        private EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public Administrator findByUsername(String username){
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Administrator a WHERE a.username=?");
            return (Administrator)query.setParameter(1,username).getSingleResult();
        }
```

And there is Administrator.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="allAdministrators", query="SELECT a FROM Administrator a")
public class Administrator {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pwd;

    public Administrator(){}

    public Administrator(String username, String name, String surname, String pwd) {
        this.username=username;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username ;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return this.pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }


    public void setSurname(String surName) {
        this.surname = surName;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Administrator adm = (Administrator) o;
        return adm.getUsername().equals(this.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getUsername().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Adinistrator"); 
        sb.append("{id='").append(id); 
        sb.append(", name='").append(name);
        sb.append(", surname='").append(surname);
        sb.append(", username='").append(username);
        sb.append("}\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And finally the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="clinic-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>PostgreSQL Database</jta-data-source>

        <class>it.clinic.model.Indicator</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.Administrator</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.Exam</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.ExamTypology</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.Medic</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.Patient</class>
        <class>it.clinic.model.Prerequisite</class>

        <properties>
             <!-- ad ogni esecuzione viene creato lo schema, cancellando il contenuto delle tabelle  
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>  -->

              <!-- SQL dialect -->
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

             <!--- Per avere info sulle istruzioni SQL inviate al db -->
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
             <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Stacktrace:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    it.clinic.persistence.ExamTypologyDaoJPA.findAll(ExamTypologyDaoJPA.java:54)
    it.clinic.facade.AdministratorFacade.getAllExamTypologies(AdministratorFacade.java:53)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:236)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:203)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    it.clinic.facade.AdministratorFacade$$LocalBeanProxy.getAllExamTypologies(it/clinic/facade/AdministratorFacade.java)
    it.clinic.controller.ExamTypologyController.examTypologiesList(ExamTypologyController.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.JavaeeInstanceManager.postConstruct(JavaeeInstanceManager.java:163)
    org.apache.tomee.mojarra.TomEEInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(TomEEInjectionProvider.java:57)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    com.sun.faces.el.ChainTypeCompositeELResolver.getValue(ChainTypeCompositeELResolver.java:90)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:96)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:115)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:151)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    org.apache.jsp.ExamTypologies_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(ExamTypologies_jsp.java:280)
    org.apache.jsp.ExamTypologies_jsp._jspService(ExamTypologies_jsp.java:232)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:642)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.WebBeansFilter.doFilter(WebBeansFilter.java:52)

I'm using JPA with Tomee and JSF 2.2.
I hope you will help me to go through this :)

Comment: you should add the NPE stack trace and possibly identify the line in your source that relates to the top of the NPE.

Comment: Added, thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
new AdministratorDaoJPA()
```

to get your DAO. So the container can't inject anything into that object, and the entityManager field thus has its default value: null.

For injection to happen, you must let the container create and inject the objects.

You also don't need the entity manager in your facade, so there is no point in injecting it there. What you need to inject is the DAO:

```
@Inject
private AdministratorDaoJPA administratorDao;
```

Comment: I have to add a private variable to the class AdministratorFacade and put the annotation "@Inject"?

I have deleted the em from facade, now it's only in the Daos.

Comment: Yes. That's what you need to do. As shown in the answer.